# getting price using bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

hi I am trying to scrape the price off a website.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'https://raymond-weil.co.uk/mens-collections/'
result = requests.get(url)
doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")

prices = doc.find_all(class_='woocommerce-Price-amount amount')

for i in prices:
    price = prices.get_text(separator=' ')
    print(price)
```

here is the HTML of the site
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZ2uz.png)

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\project\Sites\Raymond_Weil_Mens.py", line 12, in <module>
    price = prices.get_text(separator=' ')
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 2428, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get_text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

I want it to scrape the prices off the site for all products but it only works when I use .find not .find_all

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over `prices`, assigning each matching element to the `i` variable, but then trying to call the `get_text` method on `prices`. Call the method on the `i` value instead.

```py
for i in prices:
    price = i.get_text(separator=' ')
    print(price)
```